# Asking someone to perform a task without sounding pushy

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests, formality

In writing, I need to request that my doctor perform several tasks for me as soon as reasonably possible.  I am almost completely sure they will be willing to perform all these tasks.

I don't want to sound pushy or demanding.

As such, I started writing a list for them, with each item beginning with *"Can you please [task]?"*.  The problem with this is that it is a question.  What I really want to write is *"Please [task]."*, but to me, that sounds too demanding.

In English, what are good words to use to politely request that another person promptly perform a task without sounding pushy or demanding?

Comment: That's how people speak, they often phrase instructions to people as questions. "Can you pass the salt?" does not mean what it literally means. If your boss says "Could you get this done by Friday?" it's most likely an instruction or demand. If you absolutely must avoid a question form, you can say "I'd appreciate [you getting this task done]/[you doing this task]/[it if you could do (task)]. Also, grateful, or "I'd be in your debt".

Comment: Have you seen [Interpersonal Skills.SE](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com)? That might be helpful...

Comment: @marcellothearcane Yes.  It was a tough choice whether to post on this SE or that one.

Comment: You only need the politeness thing **once**.  Could you kindly perform these tasks as quickly as possible since we are a bit backed up? Then, list them below that.

Comment: Interpersonal Skills.SE 
seems a far better fit for this question, RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket.

Answer (score 0):

When making a request, starting off with "Could/can you please [task]" would be best.

[Here](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/grammar-language/difference-between-could-and-can/) is a link to the difference between 'can' and 'could' in this context, with 'could' being a bit more polite. 'Can' would also be fine to use however.

Then, you can add something like "as soon as you are able to", or add a reasonable but short time-frame that you'd like the task completed by. If it's urgent, say the day you need the task done by- but hopefully you'd able to make a request before it's super urgent.

ex.

"Could you please send the prescriptions to the drugstore by sometime next week?

Thank you,
YourName"

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use "I-messages."  This means that you talk about you.  You explain what you need and why.  Example, taken from a portal message I sent to my primary today:

> Drug X has been helpful.  The 25 mg dose seems right for me.  But there
> aren't any refills on the current prescription.  Would you send a script for it to my pharmacy,
> please?  I have about 3 days' worth left.

Comment: Down voter, care to explain?

Comment: The question is about smoothness of communication, not grammar, choice of vocabulary, punctuation etc, and should be transferred to Interpersonal Skills, not answered here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Actually, it is about choice of vocabulary (I'm the OP).

Comment: Hello, @RockPaperLz- Mask it or Casket. // I'd say that [almost?] all questions on Interpersonal Skills involve a choice of vocabulary. The tag on ELU is reserved for the subset not asking about 'not wanting to sound pushy or demanding' etc. From the 'vocabulary' tag here: 'The vocabulary tag should be used for questions discussing a multitude of words in a certain field. E.g., the vocabulary concerning money or the vocabulary concerning leatherworking.'